# Sonar Overall Coverage ignores a module

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a project with modules `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.
There are unit tests in all these modules.

However, there are (currently) no integration tests in module `A`.

- The **IT coverage** (which takes into account all modules) is roughly 15%.
- The **UT coverage** (which takes into account all modules) is roughly 35%.
- The **overall coverage** in the IT coverage widget (which for some reason takes into account only the modules with IT's, namely `B`, `C` and `D`) is roughly 70%.

According to the [official Sonar docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions#Metricdefinitions-Tests), the overall coverage is supposed to be the combined coverage of IT's and UT's, i.e. overall coverage <= [IT coverage + UT coverage].

This condition is obviously violated by the above overall coverage of 70%. 
Since the overall coverage only takes into account modules `B`,`C` and `D`, (which have an overall coverage of roughly 70%), the calculated coverage is correct (for these 3 modules).

How can I tell Sonar to consider *all* modules (also those without integration tests) in the calculation of the overall coverage such that I have a meaningful overall coverage metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-114

Comment: As a workaround, we added a dummy integration test (which does nothing) in the module which had no integration tests. The overall coverage is now displayed correctly.